# Are there any security concerns when mounting the entire host into the container (read-only)?

Tags: linux, security, docker

I am maintaining an open source software, which is a basic resources monitor for servers. To make it easier to install, the project can be used via a docker container.

That means that I have to interact with the host system a lot, though.
[One of the biggest problems is reading the disk usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72517164/9150652). Currently, I am instructing the users to bind their mounts into the container, but that complicates things a lot (users don't know where their mounts are, or simply don't read the docs).

**I was wondering if I could just mount `-v /:/mnt/host:ro`?** Technically, it seems possible and would solve my problems. But how secure is it?

I am aware that the program could read sensitive information, but the application allows no user-input, so some kind of injection should be out of question.

Comment: In case somebody is wondering - the current instructed parameters are: `-v /etc/os-release:/etc/os-release:ro -v /proc/1/ns/net:/mnt/host_ns_net:ro -v /media:/mnt/host_media:ro -v /mnt:/mnt/host_mnt:ro --privileged `

Comment: Generally speaking this would be handled by an agent on the host not the guest gaining any kind of full access to the host.